# ¿Cómo realizo templates en PHPMailer?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Actualmente tengo un formulario que envía email con variables que llegan por POST. Luego creo el email dentro de $body. Es decir, armo lo que la persona recibe con HTML. Se que si coloco previamente file_get_contents('Template_en_html_que_envío.html') entonces puedo editar mucho mejor y más rápido un archivo de puro HTML, dado que prettier lo entiende mejor y puedo enviarlo sin problemas.

Mi consulta surge por el hecho de que dentro de ese template, se pasan variables.
Lo que antes era:

```
$body = '<div style="max-width:600px;width:100%; font-size:20px;">Hola'. $nombre. '</div>
```

Ahora sería:

```
$body = file_get_contents('Template_en_html_que_envío.html')
```

El template no recibe los parametros por POST, claramente. Sino que los parametros por POST los recibe mi archivo al cual llamo al hacer submit el formulario. Pero sucede que ya no se como pasar la variable que llega por POST.

Tendría que colocar dentro del template algo como [-- NOMBRE --] y luego usar un str_replace para que antes de enviar reemplace ese trozo de cadena por una variable real? O hay mejor forma de hacerlo?